# Get all URLs opened in browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url

I want to keep track from all the browser tabs I have opened. I searched it a bit and found out that I can achieve this with this command (for Chrome) `chrome.tabs.query`

So, do I need to build an extension for Chrome for this to work or I can achieve this with some Javascript code for example? (I think the first case)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: chrome extension is the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, do I need to build an extension for Chrome for this to work

Yes. It would be a *huge* security problem if any website could monitor what happened in all other tabs open in the same browser.

> or I can achieve this with some Javascript code for example?

Chrome Extensions are written in JS.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.